# Accessing pixel values from destination image of CopyMakeBorder function in Emgu CV

Tags: vb.net, emgucv

A little bit new to EmguCV here

Just want to ask quick question, about `CopyMakeBorder` function

Are the pixel values of the destination image accessible?

I want to process further the destination image, but when I tried to access pixel values from the image, it only returns me 0 (even in the location that are not supposed to be 0, for example the central pixel). When I used Imshow, it shows that the image borders are perfectly processed, but problem only persist when I try to access the pixel values, only getting 0 wherever the pixel location is.

This is not a problem when I tried to use destination images from other EmguCV functions, such as `Threshold` Function

Can anyone clarify? Thanks A lot!!

I am using VB.net, here is the code (I am away from my workstation for the weekend so I am just gonna try to remember the code, probably some capital letters here and there are mistyped, but I hope you get the gist.)

First I initialize the source images and destination image

```
Dim img As Image(Of Gray,Byte) = New Image (Of Gray, Byte)("myimage.jpg")
Dim img1 As Image(Of Gray,Byte) = New Image (Of Gray, Byte)(img.size)
```

`CopyMakeBorder` Function, extend 1 pixel to top, bottom, left and right. Border type constant 0 values

```
Cvinvoke.CopyMakeBorder(img,img1,1,1,1,1,BorderType.Constant, New MCvscalar(0))
```

Accessing pixel values from destination image, take example pixel in x = 100, y = 100, and channel 0 (as it is a grayscale image)

```
Console.writeline(img1.data(100,100,0))
```

This will make debug output to 0, and no matter where I try to take the pixel values, it is still 0, even though when I try to show the image that specific pixel should not be 0 (it is not black)

```
Cvinvoke.Imshow("test",img1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to access the data through Image.Data, however, this doesn't include the added border(s); just the original bitmap.

The added border is in the Mat property, however. Through it the individual pixels can be accessed

```
' returns data from original bitmap
Console.WriteLine(img1.Data(100, 100, 0))
' returns data from modified bitmap
Console.WriteLine(img1.Mat.GetData(100, 100)(0))
```

Comment: As far as I understood I have to convert `Mat` to `Image(,)` if I want to set pixel values (for example if I want to iterate through the pixels).

Can I still use `Image.Data` if I convert the destination `Mat` to `Image(,)`?

Comment: `to set pixel values (for example if I want to iterate through the pixels)` these things are not the same. Well you can get the Mat into an image but it's not the same object, but a copy `Dim img2 = img1.Mat.ToImage(Of Gray, Byte)`, so you wouldn't be able to set pixels on img1 this way. However, this wasn't part of your question ;)

Comment: Hmmm okay so how do I manipulate the pixel values in the destination image? 
As far as have read in emgucv website it said that the easiest way to access pixel from destination image is to convert it into `Image(,)` and use `Image.Data`.

Comment: Yeah you could get the Image and modify pixels, then use the resulting Image as your new image i.e. put it on the form.